# How to plot multiple subgroup analysis in the same forest plot in R

Tags: r, graph, r-forestplot

Quick question about R.
It is possible to plot multiple subgroup analysis in the same forest plot (obviously suppressing contributions of individual studies)?

I am conducting one meta-analysis in which I have multiple subgroup analysis to show. To avoid generating multiple figures, I do need these subgroup analysis to be showed in the same picture.

Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I used in one of my papers.

```
forestplot(labeltext=Labels,graph.pos=3,
               mean=df[["OR"]],lower = df[["Lower.CI"]],upper=df[["Upper.CI"]],
               xlab="←  Superior - Normal - Abnormal  →",
               title = d,
               txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label=gpar(cex=0.7),
                      ticks=gpar(cex=0.7),
                      xlab=gpar(cex = 0.7),
                      title=gpar(cex = 1)),
                xticks=c(0,.5,1,1.5,2,2),
               lwd.ci=2,
               zero=1,clip=c(0,2),
              fn.ci_norm=rep(c("fpDrawCircleCI","fpDrawDiamondCI"),length(unique(Forest_df$Method))),boxsize=0.2)
```

Comment: Thx for this code. Please try to include the table used in this code and if possible, the resulting plot or its link.